# Error code 805a0193 when using Store

Tags: store, nokia-lumia-535, error

My Lumia 535 is failing to download apps or even install them, instead it gives me an error code 805a0193. I have been trying for the past 2 days now. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a server-side issue, apparently many people are reporting the same error on both Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1. Nothing to do but wait for it to be resolved.

More information here: https://www.windowslatest.com/2018/12/10/the-windows-phone-8-1-store-is-broken-with-error-805a0193/

Comment: I thought the servers have slowly been shut down.